# python subprocess gives error "The filename directory name or volume syntax is incorrect."

Tags: python

I was trying to use subprocess to open a file:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('notepad > hmm.txt')
```

or

```
subprocess.call('start excel.exe \"hmm.txt\"')
```

but it gives me the error "The filename directory name or volume syntax is incorrect".

Answer (score 1):

It's simple and silly, but I found out that including the option "shell = True" fixes this, because it then runs the command in the shell, instead of the other way subprocess calls it (which I'm not sure of...comment if you understand please).  Should be the same thing for subprocess.Popen()

```
subprocess.call('notepad > hmm.txt', shell = True)
```

or

```
subprocess.call('start excel.exe \"hmm.txt\"', shell = True)
```

also, be careful with shell = True because:

Warning Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

Comment: The `>` redirection is functionality provided by a shell, probably `cmd.exe` in your case.  You can arrange to set `stdout` to your own file object using `Popen` instead.  `start` is a shell command as well, again it doesn't do anything you can't do using `Popen`.  One of the other things a shel does on Windows is filename association.  Again you could access the registry yourself for that, but life's too short.